# Simplistic Gdim on a guitar, is this OK?

Tags: guitar, chords

I'm struggling with Gdim. The way I play it is:

```
  x
| | | | | |
| | | | 2 |
3 | | | | 4
```

I use my third finger to mute the second string but I'm not sure of the open D string. I think the chord sounds OK, but am I really playing a Gdim?

I googled Gdim and my version does not show up among the suggestions. (Tried posting to r/guitar but my post was instakilled by a modbot, yay reddit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The note D is not part of a Gdim chord. You should play the notes G-Bb-Db. One way to do this would be this slightly modified version of your suggestion (from low E to high e): 3-X-X-3-2-3

Depending on the type of guitar you have, you could fret the low G (third fret low E string) either with your thumb or with your second finger. Since Gdim is a triad, you could as well just play the top three strings if you don't need the root in the bass.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a Gdim, because it's missing a Bb and there's no D in Gdim. I wouldn't call that a simplistic Gdim or any kind of Gdim at all. A diminished G chord has a minor third (Bb note) and a diminished fifth (Db). Yours doesn't have a third at all, and it has a perfect fifth as well as a diminished fifth or sharp 11th, so it doesn't do the job of a dim chord, the thing people mean when they write a Gdim or G° chord symbol. If you want a name for your chord, you could call it "G omit3 #11".

Comment: I think the name is rather G5#11. Cool sounding chord! But indeed this is not Gdim.

Comment: @user1079505 Yeah, omit3 is called "5" too nowadays, but I don't recall seeing that written with any extra tensions. "G5" means a G power chord. How would you say "G omit3 #5" with that "5" nomenclature? ;) How about G7omit3? Would that be G5 7 or what. The whole "5" business is a half-working kludge over the existing kludge of a naming system.

Comment: G omit3 #5 would be just two notes, giving many possible interpretation possibilities. Eb? Cm?...

Comment: Also, the fact the third is missing doesn't rule it out completely as a Gdim substitute. Incomplete chord voicings are often used on guitar and other instruments. Primarily it's the presence of perfect fifth in a diminished chord which makes it not so diminished.

Comment: I like the name G5#11, and I agree it's a cool sounding chord. Not a substituted for the  diminished fifth, I see that now.

Comment: @user1079505 Speculating on the OP's (nice) chord being a working substitute for a written dim chord in some cases makes no sense in a beginner context. Depending on the situation you can use a regular minor triad, or a dominant seventh, or just about anything, in some cases, if you know what you're doing. Which is not the case here.